# Multiple '@' symbol in email address not working with .net 2005

Tags: asp.net

In our application we send email to user of applications. When our user email address is like 
paulo.macedo@company.com.br@company, it fails with exception of system.net.mime.mailbnfhelper.readmailaddress

So can a email address have multiple '@' symbol and can .net MailMessege object handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to have few @ signs, but you have to put other one in quotes.

Comment: +1 strange but true, "this@isvalid"@example.com is a valid address according to the [spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.2.1). I bet there are not many web clients and servers that will allow you to create and use addresses like those though...

Comment: @paolo: the section you linked to deals with backslash escapes (the RFC calls these "quoted-pairs"). What you meant was "quoted strings" (section 3.2.4).

Answer (score 6):

No, that's not a valid e-mail address. See [RFC-5322, section 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) and [section 3.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.3) for the lists of characters allowed in each of the parts (the definition of the atoms).

In order to have multiple '@' symbols you need to use [quoted strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.4). Apparently `MailAddress` does not support these (but does not document it). I'm running .NET 3.5 on a Win7 machine and `MailAddress` throws a `FormatException` when fed one of these.